while connecting my db with tableu i get this error
while connecting with db with postgrese i am facing this why?
Unable to complete action
Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
Error Code: D84EA4A5
FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "'Asia/Kolkata'"
Generic JDBC connection error
FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "'Asia/Kolkata'"
tried solving it and adding this time zone in postgresql but didnt work why???

Simple question first - are you using the PostgreSQL specific driver or a generic JDBC driver? You can get info and links to drivers for Tableau at https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers

Second question - do you get the same error connecting to your database from another client application, such as pgsql? Or is it only when connecting from Tableau Desktop?
